# Is my python environment broken? Unable to install gastrodon using PIP

Tags: python, metadata, environment

Using Python 3.8 on Windows, having installed a number of other modules I have tried to install gastrodon with

```
(property) C:\Users\andyt>pip install gastrodon
```

The result is this:

```
Requirement already satisfied: gastrodon in c:\users\andyt\anaconda3\envs\property\lib\site-packages (0.9.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in c:\users\andyt\anaconda3\envs\property\lib\site-packages (from gastrodon) (1.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: IPython in c:\users\andyt\anaconda3\envs\property\lib\site-packages (from gastrodon) (7.13.0)
WARNING: No metadata found in c:\users\andyt\anaconda3\envs\property\lib\site-packages
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\\users\\andyt\\anaconda3\\envs\\property\\lib\\site-packages\\ipython-7.13.0.dist-info\\METADATA'
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? I am able to install it in base...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried turning it on and off again? I mean potentially uninstall and reinstall it. I had a similar problem downloading numpy a while back and that seemed to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

so I renamed metadata.json to metadata in a few similar positions where the install failed sequentially, and it appeared to have been successful, except I am now dealing with another error when trying to import gastrodon...